# Python как остановить цикл по клику пункта меню?

Tags: python, циклы, tkinter, анимация

Всем привет! В универе по лабораторной работе задали следующую задачу:

> На пространстве формы изображена матрица случайных чисел от 0 до 99 размером
> 6х6. Метка в виде овала исходно находится в левом верхнем углу, а после запуска
> циклически движется по периметру матрицы по часовой стрелке с дискретом времени
> 0.8 сек. После окончания полного цикла рамка движется против часовой стрелки, а
> затем снова по часовой. Запуск движения – двойной щелчок левой клавиши мыши по
> форме, остановка – команда главного меню, что приводит к установке рамки в
> исходное положение.

Думаю, здесь с рамкой опечатка, и имелся в виду овал.

Не могу никак разобраться с остановкой цикла по щелчку пункта меню.
Принцип выполнения задачи в коде у меня такой: по двойному клику по канвасу вызывается функция start, которая вызывает функцию move_clockwise. Та, отработав полный цикл, вызывает move_counterclockwise. И в итоге они вызывают друг друга по очереди.
Остался нерешённым вопрос про остановку. Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как её можно реализовать?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
#from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Лабораторная работа №4")
root.geometry('360x360')

width=360
height=360
sleep=0.01
step=15
work=True

c = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg="white")
c.place(x = 0, y = 0)
oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill='green')

def move_clockwise():
    for i in range((width - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, step, 0)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)

    for i in range((height - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, 0, step)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)

    for i in range((width - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, -step, 0)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)

    for i in range((height - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, 0, -step)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)
    move_counterclockwise()

def move_counterclockwise():
    for i in range((height - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, 0, step)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)
    for i in range((width - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, step, 0)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)
    for i in range((height - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, 0, -step)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)
    for i in range((width - 30) // step):
        c.move(oval, -step, 0)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(sleep)
    move_clockwise()

def start(event):
    global work
    while work:
        move_clockwise()

def stop():
    global work
    if work:
        work==False


#Заполнение матрицы
for x in range(6):
    for y in range(6):
        text=c.create_text(30+60*x, 30+60*y, text=str(random.randint(0,99)))

c.bind('<Double-Button-1>', start)

menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label="Stop", command=stop)


root.mainloop()
```

P.S. Пожалуйста, по возможности ООП не предлагать, преподаватель его не поддерживает...

Comment: Что значит преподаватель не поддерживает ООП. Не применять в данном задании или вообще не практикует ООП?

Comment: В данном задании точно не стоит применять, т.к. в рамках курса мы ООП не проходили. Насчёт него самого не известно, практикует ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одна опечатка и одна принципиальная ошибка.

Опечатка в присваивании:

```
    if work:
        work==False   # должно быть просто =
```

А ошибка в том, что вы снова вызываете `move_clockwise()` в конце функции `def move_counterclockwise()`. В результате функции уходят в рекурсию и никогда не возвращаются в цикл проверки условия на останов:

```
    while work:
        move_clockwise()
```

Ну и `work = True` надо бы добавить в начало `def start(event):`. Чтобы можно было снова запустить движение овала.

---

Ну а вообще, код можно подсократить. И останавливаться мгновенно.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
#from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Лабораторная работа №4")
root.geometry('360x360')

width=360
height=360
sleep=0.02
step=15
work=False

c = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg="white")
c.place(x = 0, y = 0)
oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill='green')

def move(figure):
    while True:
        for vertical, increment in ((False, +1), (True , +1), (False, -1), (True , -1),  # по часовой
                                    (True , +1), (False, +1), (True , -1), (False, -1)): # против часовой
            for i in range(((height if vertical else width) - 30) // step):
                if not work: 
                    c.coords(figure, 0, 0, 30, 30)
                    return
                c.move(figure, (0 if vertical else 1) * step * increment, (1 if vertical else 0) * step * increment)
                root.update()
                time.sleep(sleep)


def start(event):
    global work
    if not work:
        work = True
        move(oval)

def stop():
    global work
    work = False


#Заполнение матрицы
for x in range(6):
    for y in range(6):
        text=c.create_text(30+60*x, 30+60*y, text=str(random.randint(0,99)))

c.bind('<Double-Button-1>', start)

menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label="Stop", command=stop)

root.mainloop()
```

---

К тому же задание довольно невнятное. С учётом того, что движение должно происходить с дискретом 0.8 секунды (а это довольно большая пауза), возможно имелось ввиду, что овал должен прыгать по элементам матрицы. И в таком случае `time.sleep()` вообще применять нельзя, т.к. он будет фризить интерфейс на это время. Нужно использовать функцию `after()` для отложенного запуска следующего перемещения. Например, с использованием генератора, код может выглядеть так:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
#from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Лабораторная работа №4")

sleep = 0.8
step = 60
oval_size = 40
matrix_size = {"W":6, "H":6} # width, height
offset = (step - oval_size) // 2
work = False

root.geometry(f'{matrix_size["W"] * step}x{matrix_size["H"] * step}')
c = Canvas(root, width=matrix_size["W"] * step, height=matrix_size["H"] * step, bg="white")
c.place(x = 0, y = 0)
oval = c.create_oval(offset, offset, offset + oval_size, offset + oval_size)

def move(gen=None):
    if work: 
        next(gen)
        root.after(int(sleep*1000), lambda: move(gen))

def move_generator():
    while True:
        for vertical, increment in ((False, +1), (True , +1), (False, -1), (True , -1),  # по часовой
                                    (True , +1), (False, +1), (True , -1), (False, -1)): # против часовой
            for i in range(matrix_size["H" if vertical else "W"] - 1):
                c.move(oval, (0 if vertical else 1) * step * increment, (1 if vertical else 0) * step * increment)
                yield


def start(event):
    global work
    if not work:
        work = True
        move(move_generator())

def stop():
    global work
    work = False
    c.coords(oval, offset, offset, offset + oval_size, offset + oval_size)


#Заполнение матрицы
for x in range(6):
    for y in range(6):
        text=c.create_text(30+60*x, 30+60*y, text=str(random.randint(0,99)))

c.bind('<Double-Button-1>', start)

menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label="Stop", command=stop)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Оно же без использования генератора.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Лабораторная работа №4")

sleep = 0.8
step = 60
oval_size = 40
matrix_size = {"W":6, "H":6} # width, height
offset = (step - oval_size) // 2
work = False

root.geometry(f'{matrix_size["W"] * step}x{matrix_size["H"] * step}')
c = Canvas(root, width=matrix_size["W"] * step, height=matrix_size["H"] * step, bg="white")
c.place(x = 0, y = 0)
oval = c.create_oval(offset, offset, offset + oval_size, offset + oval_size)

movements = []
for vertical, increment in ((False, +1), (True , +1), (False, -1), (True , -1),  # по часовой
                            (True , +1), (False, +1), (True , -1), (False, -1)): # против часовой
    for i in range(matrix_size["H" if vertical else "W"] - 1):
        movements.append(((0 if vertical else 1) * step * increment, (1 if vertical else 0) * step * increment))


def move(pos=0):
    if work: 
        c.move(oval, *movements[pos])
        root.after(int(sleep*1000), lambda: move( (pos+1) % len(movements) ))


def start(event):
    global work
    if not work:
        work = True
        move()

def stop():
    global work
    work = False
    c.coords(oval, offset, offset, offset + oval_size, offset + oval_size)


#Заполнение матрицы
for x in range(6):
    for y in range(6):
        text=c.create_text(30+60*x, 30+60*y, text=str(random.randint(0,99)))

c.bind('<Double-Button-1>', start)

menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label="Stop", command=stop)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы, кажется, лучше поняли, что требуется в задании :) Остался только один вопрос: можно ли реализовать функцию без использования генератора? Например, c помощью return или списков? И можно ли, например, не передавать в функцию move параметр gen, а вызвать метод after несколько раз, с разными функциями?

Comment: Я добавил вариант без генератора. С предварительным созданием списка перемещений и пошаговому проходу по нему.

Comment: Благодарю! Примерно то, что я имела в виду :)

Comment: Можно также уточнить, для чего в функции move нужно считать остаток деления  (pos+1) % len(movements)? И каким образом итерируется pos?

Comment: Остаток от деления - чтобы при достижения конца списка `pos` стал нулём. И итерируется он просто - каждый последующий вызов `move` делается с `pos+1`. Т.е., вызванный `move(0)` внутри себя планирует следующий вызов себя же как `move(1)`. Вызванный `move(1)` планирует позвать уже `move(2)`. И т.д. А последний (скажем длина списка была, к примеру, 10) вызванный `move(9)` должен был бы запланировать `move(10)`. Но т.к. берётся остаток от длины списка, то будет `move(10 % 10)`, т.е. `move(0)`, т.е. всё начнётся с начала.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!